# windows security update code

Tags: windows, exploit

I'm not an expert with Windows administrations, but while I was testing Windows 7 exploits with malware known as sand worms (ms14-060) I saw that even performing all procedures correctly, the exploit never could. Then I thought that, since the vulnerability was discovered in 2014 and I have installed windows 7 on virtual machines only a few weeks ago, it could be that the version I have installed had already fixed the bug. In the history of windows update I saw that there is, however, no update of security with KB3000869 code (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/security/ms14-060.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396), so not sure if the vulnerability has been patched or not.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What software are you using? The exploit is only reliable in a few specific versions. Server 2013 / office 2010 SP2 are your best bet:

https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/windows/fileformat/ms14_060_sandworm

Comment: Hi JAK. I'm using office 2010 SP2 and windows 7 64 bit SP1.

Comment: Windows 7 isn't the applicable Windows Server version